# datebox format as mm/dd/YYYY How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datebox

How do you change date format in date box? there are lots of different examples, none seem to work for me. Here is working JSFiddle of popup but I need date format like 11/07/2013.

Tried:
"dateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y" and "overrideDateFormat":"%m/%d/%Y"

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
     <h1>My page</h1> 
    <a  data-role="button" id="myplus" class="ui-btn-right" >+</a>
    <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "hideInput": "true", "centerHoriz": "true", "closeCallback":"onCLoseMyDate();"}' />
</div>

<div data-role="content">

</div>
```

[Working Fiddle not correct format](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LS3g6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found at http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/events.html, under "Public Functions"

```
$('element').datebox('callFormat', <format> <date>)
```

As applied to your [[updated]](http://jsfiddle.net/LS3g6/6/) fiddle:

```
var dateObject = $('#mydate').datebox('getTheDate'),
    theDate =  $('#mydate').datebox('callFormat', '%m/%d/%Y', dateObject);
alert(theDate);
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I have been looking for the list of public functions on jtsage.com for days... their help site is not very obvious.

Comment: aye.  it's a terrible idea for the developer to write the help documents - because I already know how it works, so explaining to someone who does not isn't always intuitive - at least not for me.